# Constructor pointer changes

Tags: c++

I have a file `test.cpp`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
class B {
    public:
            B() {}
};
class A {
    public:
            A(B *b) {
                    b = b;
            }
            B *b;
};
int main() {
    B b = B();
    A a = A(&b);
    printf("b: %p\n", &b);
    printf("a.b: %p\n", a.b);
}
```

Compiled under `g++ -Wall -std=c++11 test.cpp` and ran, gives results:

```
b: 0x7fffc7e9fa6f
a.b: 0x7fffc7e9fb60
```

I had assumed that the pointers were copied directly for the constructor, but we see that the values kept in the `A` instance of the `B` class has changed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit** -- Regarding the discussion that this question may be off-topic:

I do not believe this to be a "simple typographical error" as the name scoping error is not immediately obvious in this context.

- This *was* a program created in an isolated environment intended to demonstrate the error.
- In Python, for example, such a method of class variable assignment is allowed. While the merits of such naming schemes can be left up to debate, there *is* a reasonable basis of confusion here.
- I have also searched for solutions to this (admittedly quite naive) problem, and could also not easily find a solution online.

**Edit Edit** -- It is clear that this question has been thoroughly answered and thus does not need further responses. The reason for closing being "off-topic" is debatable, however, as noted previously.

Comment: Turn on more compiler warnings (although I would have guessed `-Wall` catches this). On second thought, never mind. It's Clang that warns about this. As an aside, `B b;` and `A a(&b);` work just as well, and the argument to `printf` for `%p` should be a `void *` (this doesn't happen with `std::cout`).

Comment: The statement `b = b;` is a self-assignment. For a valid pointer value it has no effect whatsoever, other than possibly using a nano-sec or two.

Comment: The perils of naming variables that are not distinct :) :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In `b = b`, both occurences of `b` refer to the constructor parameter. The member is left uninitialised.

Solutions:

- use an initialiser list, `A(B *b) : b(b) {}`
- rename the parameter so it doesn't hide the member
- refer to the member as `this->b`

Comment: Perhaps mention that we recommend renaming.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: Speak for yourself. I'd recommend an initialiser list, if anyone wanted my recommendation.

Comment: Good reasons for renaming the member so that it's not hidden by the parameter include (1) more clear what a name refers to, and (2) it's the almost universal convention. That does not preclude using an initializer list. I would do both.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: (1) it's just as clear, unless the constructor is too complicated; (2) I must live in a different universe to you. (And, if you do rename it, there's a danger of accidentally self-initialising it in the initialiser list).

Comment: Thanks -- I guess I was in Python mode for a second here =P

Also, I forgot I should probably use `_b` as well to circumvent precisely these kinds of issues (private scoping, yadda yadda yadda, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

Rewrite `A::A()` as

```
A(B *b) {
    this->b = b;
}
```

Otherwise, both `b`s in `b = b;` refer to the same variable: the parameter.

Answer (score 2):

change the constructor of A to

```
A(B *b) : b(b) {}
```

Answer (score 2):

As I'm writing this one answer has already been selected as “the” solution.

The problem, a self-assignment `b = b;`, stems from using the same name `b` for two different things –, so that the two meanings were confused.

The selected-as-solution answer does include as a possibility to *use different names for different things*, but it restricts that to renaming the parameter, and it recommends to keep the proven-as-confusing identical names.

---

Since the problem stems directly from using identical names for different things, the most direct solution is to use different names for different things.

In the case at hand the easiest way to achieve that, is to remove the constructor, so that there is only the data member left – with its now unique name.

Then the original code …

```
class A {
    public:
            A(B *b) {
                    b = b;
            }
            B *b;
};
```

becomes, for example, just …

```
struct A { B* b; };
```

and an original instantiation `A a( p );` becomes `A a{ p };`.

Much simpler.

---

Having a constructor implies at least the possibility of class invariant, in which case it's prudent to limit access to the data members.

The almost universal convention is to use some prefix or suffix for non-`public` member variables. E.g. Microsoft uses an `m` prefix, while many other use an underscore suffix. (An underscore as a prefix is reserved for the implementation in the global namespace.)

Using the underscore suffix convention for data members, and replacing assignment with the more generally applicable memory initializer, the original becomes something like this:

```
class A
{
private:
    B* b_;

public:
    auto b() const
        -> B*
    { return b_; }

    A( B* b_value )
        : b_( b_value )
    {}
};
```

The simple `struct` shown earlier suffices if there is no class invariant, while this more verbose & complicated code (or equivalent) is what's needed for safely maintaining a class invariant. The original code was in-between. Not simple enough for the simple data struct case, but not safe enough for the has-invariant case.

---

<sup>Renaming the parameter so that it doesn't hide the member is problematic because it keeps the halfway between simple and safe abstraction level. That's also a problem with the idea of referring to the member as `this->b`. And using an initializer list `A(B *b) : b(b) {}` is problematic because it relies on a subtlety of the language, so that most ordinary C++ programmers probably will have to at least think twice to ensure themselves about correctness, and so that at least some will think that it must be erroneous.</sup>